# Pandas: concatenate some df

Tags: python, pandas

I have two df

```
ID   url   visits
123  vk.com   14
789  twitter.com   7
```

And

```
ID   url  buys
123  vk.com   3
456  facebook.com  1
```

Desire output

```
ID   url   visits   buys
123  vk.com   14    3
456  facebook.com   NaN   1
789  twitter.com   7   NaN
```

I try

```
result = pd.concat([short, short1], axis=1, ignore_index=False)
```

But it doesn't look like my desire output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) on columns `ID` and `url` with outer join by parameter `how='outer'`:

```
result = pd.merge(short, short1, on=['ID','url'], how='outer')
print (result)
      ID           url  visits  buys
0  123.0        vk.com    14.0   3.0
1  789.0   twitter.com     7.0   NaN
2  456.0  facebook.com     NaN   1.0
```

Comment: it returns `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5, 23558), indices imply (5, 7087)`